# How do I show a background image in the first part of a page and make it cover 100% of the visible part of the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to development and have been tasked with a task that seems a bit challenging.

I have to create a one page website where in the navigation I have about us and contact us link.  When the user clicks on about us the user's screen should scroll to that section on the page and same thing for contact us.  I was able to accomplish this.

What do I need help with?

I am using a background image that I want to cover the user's screen width and height that way the 2nd section isn't shown if a user has a larger screen.

This is how I have stuff stacked:

```
<div class="header">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.jpg">
<a href="#about" class="link">
<a href="#contact" class="link">
</div>
<div class="part1">
some content
</div>
<div class="part2" aboutus" id="about">
About us
</div>
<div class="part3 contactus" id="contact>
Contact us
</div>
```

So Part 1 is the first thing the user sees along with the header.

**Question:**

How do I display a background image that only appears in part1 **and covers the entire width and height of the user's screen regarldess of how small or big it is.**  I am sure I need JQuery or some CSS structuring but not sure where to start.

What can I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
.part1 {
    background: url(bkgd.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JS:** using jquery

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".part1").css("min-height", $(window).height());    
}); 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".part1").css("min-height", $(window).height());
});
```

See [demo updated](http://jsfiddle.net/rDQA3/5/)

**Upadted:**
Adjust `.part` background size using `background-size` set to the cover keyword and center the background view. Also using jquery to set the minimum height of `.part` equal to window height to fit the view port dynamically.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve the issue with the part2 still being visible.

Comment: @ariel Can you see demo and say what's the problem?

Comment: Part 1 should cover the user's entire screen.  REgardless of how big the height and width are.  I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Do you want to resize `.part1` when the window resized?

Comment: Yes, so that even if a user has a very big screen part1 will still cover that entire screen.  Thanks for understanding Vahid.

Comment: You are a genius my friend! That worked.  I'll report back here if it doesn't work on a larger screen or something.

Comment: @ariel also you can remove `fixed` from css background maybe needed

Comment: So what is `background-size` what does that do? what does the `cover` part do? I don't understand how this works becuase there is no explanation. What makes it fullscreen is it the `center center` or the `width` or the `background-size`?

Comment: @Pinocchio sorry for less info. It's my bad. Updated so.

Answer (score 2):

```
 .part1{
    background: url(http://someurl.com/someimg.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
 }
```

Set the background size and set the div to have full height and width

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <img src="logo.jpg" class="logo"/> 

      <a href="#" onClick="scrollContent('about')" class="about">About</a>
      <a href="#" onClick="scrollContent('contact')" class="contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="part1">
    <div class="part1-wrapper">
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="part2 about" id="about">
    <div class="part2-wrapper">
      <!-- About us -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="part3 contactus" id="contact">
    <div class="part3-wrapper">
       <!-- Contact us -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.header {
  background: #666;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.header a {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px 18px 0 0;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff;

  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.header a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.part1,
.part2,
.part3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
.part1 {
  background: #aaa;
}
.part2 {
  background: #ccc;
}
.part3 {
  background: #eee;
}
.part1-wrapper,
.part2-wrapper,
.part3-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function scrollContent(id) {
  $( 'html, body' ).stop().animate({ scrollTop: $( '#' + id ).offset().top }, 1200 );
}

$(function () {

  var parts = $('.part1, .part2, .part3');

  parts
    .css({
      height: $(window).innerHeight(),
      width: $(window).innerWidth() 
    });

});
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/VJxeH/

Comment: Please explain what is going on here. I have no clue.

Comment: @ariel asked "How do I display a background image that only appears in part1 and covers the entire width and height of the user's screen regarldess of how small or big it is?"

Comment: Yes, I didn't say it wasn't correct, I said I don't understand what is going on / how it works.

Comment: @Pinocchio Set background image for part1 than with jquery dynamically set height for part1 and on window resize update height for part1. Look at the fiddle. P.S. I edited fiddle a couple of times ;)